# How to know if a class inherits other abstract class?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an abstract `Draggable` class which inherits `QWidget`. Other two classes inherit `Draggable`:

```
             QWidget
                |
            Draggable (abstract)
              /   \
             /     \
          Class1  Class2
```

In the main window, on mouse press event I want to know if the child that was clicked is `Draggable`:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QWidget *childWid = childAt(event->pos());
    if (!childWid)
        return;

    // if Draggable is not abstract I can do as below
    /*
    Dragable *obj = new Dragable;
    if (!childWid->metaObject()->inherits(obj->metaObject()))
        return;
    */
}
```

I can check by comparing `childWid->metaObject()->className()` to `Class1` and `Class2` but the `Draggable` has lots of children. So I want to know how to find out if the child inherits `Draggable`?

Comment: You might use `qobject_cast<Draggable *>(child) == nullptr` check, for example. To make it work `Draggable` should be declared with the Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: @vahancho what does that mean?

Comment: Btw, you are avoiding dependency inversion principle from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach is using [qobject_cast](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) function, which is similar to `dynamic_cast`, but works only for `QObjects`. The benefit of using `qobject_cast` vs `dynamic_cast` is that the former will work even if RTTI is disabled.

The precondition is that your `Draggable` class should inherit `QObject` directly or indirectly, which it actually does, and declared with `Q_OBJECT` macro. I.e.

```
class Draggable : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
[..]
};
```

and in your example:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QWidget *childWid = childAt(event->pos());
    if (!childWid)
        return;

    // if Draggable is not abstract I can do as below
    if (!qobject_cast<Draggable *>(childWid))
    {
        // Not a Draggable
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic_cast

```
if (auto *draggable = dynamic_cast<Draggable*>(childWid)) {
    do_stuff()
}
```

Comment: Why not `qobject_cast`? `dynamic_cast is too slow, expecially on MSVC compiler.

Comment: why not static_cast?

Comment: How do you plan to check object type in **runtime** with `static_cast`?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov does qobject_cast check type in runtime o0?

Comment: @AndreySemenov yes we can qobject_cast<> runtime.

Comment: @AndreySemenov yes, it works in runtime. And it's do it very fast = O(n). You may [read documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast). You mentioned `std::is_base_of` - it works only in compile time.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to instantiate `Dragable`. It has a class metaobject that you can use: `staticMetaObject`.

Thus, in spite of `qobject_cast` being the preferred solution, the most direct fix to your code would be:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    auto *child = childAt(event->pos());
    if (!child)
        return;
    if (!child->metaObject()->inherits(&Draggable::staticMetaObject))
        return;
    auto *draggable = static_cast<Draggable*>(child);
    qDebug() << draggable;
}
```

The `qobject_cast` variant would be more concise:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    auto *draggable = qobject_cast<Draggable*>(childAt(event->pos()));
    if (!draggable)
        return;
    qDebug() << draggable;
}
```